# C++ : getting strange values for my character array when converting to int and adding

Tags: c++, arrays

The problem I'm writing code to solve is:

> A number can be broken into different contiguous sub-subsequence
>   parts.  Suppose, a number 3245 can be broken into parts like 3 2 4 5
>   32 24 45 324 245.  And this number is a COLORFUL number, since product
>   of every digit of a contiguous subsequence is different. Return 1 if
>   argument int A is a colorful number and return 0 otherwise.

My code is as follows. Everything seems to be working, except I can't seem to get the correct value for `int result`, or more specifically `(int)array[k]`. For the number 23, I got the sum of 2 as 51, 2+3 as 101, and 3 as 51. What is happening here? I believe my syntax is correct (?).

```
int Solution::colorful(int A) {
    int result=0;
    unordered_map<int,int> map1;

    string s = to_string(A);
    const char array = s.c_str();
    int n = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            result = 0;
            for (int k = i; k <=j; k++) {
                result += (int)array[k];
            }
            if (map1.find(result) == map1.end()) {
                map1.insert({result,0});
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT - okay I figured this was happening. I am getting the character value and not the integer value. How can I convert character 2 to the actual value of 2?

Comment: where do you do multiplication? "product of every digit" means that you supposed to multiply digits.

Comment: I totally meant for '+' to be '*' . Currently debugging!

Answer (score 3):

For "converting" a character value like `'2'` to an integral value `2`, you'd just substract the ASCII-value of `'0'`, i.e. `int valOfDigit = array[k] - '0'`;

Note that `atoi` or `strtod` will not work in your case, since these functions require a `'\0'`-terminated "string" as input, not a single character.

Further, to make sure that your input contains only digits, you could check each `array[k]`, e.g. by using `isdigit(array[k])` or by `(array[k] >= '0' && array[k] <= '9')`.

Comment: This subtraction method works well *if* the input is valid. If there's a chance of invalid input you can use a simple 256-byte look-up table.

Comment: @tadam: right, thanks; but I'd rather check the input and react accordingly instead of the lookup table. Adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: `isdigit()` is a good way of hardening this against user error. Good call.

Comment: `isdigit` may be implemented by a 256-byte lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) to convert a `char *` string to an int. Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: `atoi` requires 0-terminated string as input; I think this will be hard to accomplish in this scenario, where the input is `array[k]`...

Comment: _@frslm_ That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

Or just use an int cast like shown here: (int)

Comment: You can cast `char` to `int`, but that certainly won't do what the OP actually wants.